# Numbers are converted to strings in GraphQL when using gatsby-source-google-spreadsheet plugin with GatsBy

Tags: google-sheets, graphql, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby and I'm trying to use a spreadsheet file as backend data, so I prefer to use `gatsby-source-google-spreadsheet` plugin to transform the spreadsheet to GraphQL.
As you can see in this image, The format of my data is Number:
[image]
But after transferring data to GraphQL the format is changed to String
[image]

How can I have numbers in GraphQL?
Is there any configuration that I can do either in a spreadsheet or plugin?

Comment: Maybe you can cast the result when you perform the graphql query. eg. request `score:[Int]` instead of just `score`.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @player0 No I can't do this, but as I said in the question section all of the data have a number format.

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin

> gatsby-source-google-sheets
> https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-google-sheets/

You used an older version of, "Gatsby-source-google-sheet" npm plugin.
You should update this npm plugin, you must add "s" character after the "gatsby-source-google-sheet"

Follow the update command line, "npm i gatsby-source-google-sheets" or "yarn add gatsby-source-google-sheets"